# how to handle control spacing in WPF window designer?

Tags: wpf, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

I'm trying to lay out controls in a WPF window in Visual Studio 2012, using Designer.
I want to adhere to MS guidelines, in particular - to recommended spacing between controls, as specified [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa511279.aspx#controlspacing).

In Windows Forms Designer, I could've set margin a control (for example top margin of 14 for unrelated controls, or 7 for related) - and drag it - the light blue line to adjacent control would be my margin (between `label1` and `button1` on the picture):

[image]

In WPF, snaplines seem to be hardcoded to 10 pixels/units to container (thicker red line), and 5 pixels between controls (thinner red line):

[image]

Is there any way to adjust the WPF Designer snaplines size?

Or any other way to conveniently adjust spacing between controls as per MS guidelines?

UPDATE: I'm positioning controls within WPF Grid. I could've used StackPanel and set Margin for each control by hand, but it defies the purpose of Designer - visually designing a layout.

Comment: You might be able to use styles: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb613570(v=vs.100).aspx  From that page: "Windows Presentation Foundation (WPF) styling and templating refer to a suite of features (styles, templates, triggers, and storyboards) that allow an application, document, or user interface (UI) designer to create visually compelling applications and to standardize on a particular look for their product."

Comment: @Steve, can you elaborate - how I can use styles to control controls' spacing within Grid?

Comment: If you want to achieve a professional design in WPF, I strongly suggest that you learn and use XAML properly rather than relying on the designer. The Visual Studio WPF designer generates fixed-size, fixed-position layouts with are useless in a resolution-independent UI. Plus manually writing XAML can prove to be more productive than using the designer because you not only define layout but also DataBindings declaratively. This is very different from the "traditional" winforms procedural approach, which requires tons of horrible code to do anything, and does not allow any kind of customization.

Comment: @Ixa, I cannot help you beyond pointing you in that direction, which I believe is the way to go, as I don't have much experience myself with styles.